# Can stdout/stderr of a C/C++ library be caught by Rust?

Tags: rust

I am wrapping a C/C++ library in a Rust crate and calling into it using FFI (I am *not* using a subprocess).

This library logs to stdout/stderr (using, say, `printf()` or `std::cout`) but I would like to "catch" this output and use Rust's `log` crate to control the output.

Is it possible to redirect stdout/stderr of FFI calls to `log`?

Comment: Are you OK with completely preventing *any* output to stdout / stderr?

Comment: Yes, but you'll probably need to use unsafe and OS-specific code. On Unix-like OS-es, for example, you can use `dup2()` to redirect the stdout to a pipe, read that pipe from a background Rust thread, and invoke `log` as appropriate.

Comment: I am ok with _all_ output being redirected; I want the rust part to "manage" the logging... Would redirecting stdout (using say `dup2()`) change it for the rust code too? I would say yes...

Comment: Yes, but you could undo the effect after the FFI code is done. (Undoing it is reasonably cheap, boiling down to several syscalls.) You'd also have to be careful for Rust logging to delay the output until the hack is undone, otherwise it might get into an infinite loop.

Answer (score 2):

Please find below an example illustrating the different
steps to redirect/restore stderr (file descriptor 2).

The (C-like) style used here was intended in order to keep this
example minimal ; of course, you could probably use the `libc`
crate and encapsulate properly all of this in a `struct`.

Note that, *in trivial cases*, you may repeat the
*redirect/invoke/obtain/restore* sequence as many times as you want,
provided you keep `pipe_fd`, `saved_fd` and `log_file` open.

However, in non-trivial cases, some kind of complication is implied:

- if the C code produces a *quite* long message, how can we detect
  that we have read it all?

  - we could inject an end-marker into `STDERR_FILENO` after the
    message is produced at the *invoke* step and then read `log_file`
    until this marker is detected in the *obtain* step. (this adds
    some kind of text processing)
  - we could recreate the pipe and `log_file` before each *redirect*
    step, close the `PIPE_WRITE` end before the *invoke* step, read
    `log_file` until EOF is reached and close it in the *obtain* step.
    (this adds the overhead of more system-calls)
- if the C code produces a *very* long message, wouldn't it exceed
  the pipe's internal buffer capacity (and then block writing)?

  - we could execute the *invoke* step in a separate thread and
    `join()` it after the *obtain* step has completed (end-marker or
    EOF is reached), so that the invocation still *looks* serial
    from the application's point of view.
    (this adds the overhead of spawning/joining a thread)
  - an alternative is to put all the logging part of the application
    in a separate thread (spawned once for all) and keep all the
    *invocation* steps serial.
    (if the logging part of the application does not have to be
    perceived as serial this is OK, but else this just reports the
    same problem one thread further)
  - we could `fork()` to perform the *redirect* and *invoke*
    steps in a child process (if the application data does not have
    to be altered, just read), get rid of the *restore* step and
    `wait()` the process after the *obtain* step has completed
    (end-marker or EOF is reached), so that the invocation still
    *looks* serial from the application's point of view.
    (this adds the overhead of spawning/waiting a process, and
    precludes the ability to alter the application data from the
    invoked code)

```rust
// necessary for the redirection
extern "C" {
    fn pipe(fd: *mut i32) -> i32;
    fn close(fd: i32) -> i32;
    fn dup(fd: i32) -> i32;
    fn dup2(
        old_fd: i32,
        new_fd: i32,
    ) -> i32;
}
const PIPE_READ: usize = 0;
const PIPE_WRITE: usize = 1;
const STDERR_FILENO: i32 = 2;

fn main() {
    //
    // duplicate original stderr in order to restore it
    //
    let saved_stderr = unsafe { dup(STDERR_FILENO) };
    if saved_stderr == -1 {
        eprintln!("cannot duplicate stderr");
        return;
    }
    //
    // create resources (pipe + file reading from it)
    //
    let mut pipe_fd = [-1; 2];
    if unsafe { pipe(&mut pipe_fd[0]) } == -1 {
        eprintln!("cannot create pipe");
        return;
    }
    use std::os::unix::io::FromRawFd;
    let mut log_file =
        unsafe { std::fs::File::from_raw_fd(pipe_fd[PIPE_READ]) };
    //
    // redirect stderr to pipe/log_file
    //
    if unsafe { dup2(pipe_fd[PIPE_WRITE], STDERR_FILENO) } == -1 {
        eprintln!("cannot redirect stderr to pipe");
        return;
    }
    //
    // invoke some C code that should write to stderr
    //
    extern "C" {
        fn perror(txt: *const u8);
    }
    unsafe {
        dup(-1); // invalid syscall in order to set errno (used by perror)
        perror(&"something bad happened\0".as_bytes()[0]);
    };
    //
    // obtain the previous message
    //
    use std::io::Read;
    let mut buffer = [0_u8; 100];
    if let Ok(sz) = log_file.read(&mut buffer) {
        println!(
            "message ({} bytes): {:?}",
            sz,
            std::str::from_utf8(&buffer[0..sz]).unwrap(),
        );
    }
    //
    // restore initial stderr
    //
    unsafe { dup2(saved_stderr, STDERR_FILENO) };
    //
    // close resources
    //
    unsafe {
        close(saved_stderr);
        // pipe_fd[PIPE_READ] will be closed by log_file
        close(pipe_fd[PIPE_WRITE]);
    };
}
```

Comment: If there's a lot of output this approach will hang when the pipe buffer fills. To avoid that you need to have the reading occur in a separate thread concurrently with the writing.

Comment: @MichaelAnderson I agree. My intent was to keep the example simple in order to focus on the important steps. But your comment pointed out the need for some explanations about some less trivial situations.